# Inverted colors in Tensorboard SummaryWriter add_image() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensorboard, torch

There is an image stored in `image_tensor` (image_tensor of size `(3,256,512)`, storing values in the interval `0,255`)  which I would like to display in Tensorboard (TensorboardX for PyTorch, more specifically) via the add_image() function for SummaryWriter. When I add the image to the Tensorboard via `writer.add_image("color_image",image_tensor,self.step)`,  the colors are inverted.

When I write the image to a file via `scipy.misc.imsave("/write/to/path/image.png",np.transpose(image_tensor.data.cpu().numpy(),(1,2,0)))`, the image is perfectly fine.

Only thing I change for the second line is changing CxHxW to HxWxC, but I don't think that this is the root of this color inversion issue. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where I was also unable to track the problem. The solution that worked for me but is unfortunately a little bit cumbersome is:

Take your image and plug it into a matplotlib figure then use `add_figure`.

For example:

```
fig, ax =  plt.subplots(2,3)
# add your subplots with some images eg.
ax[0,0].imshow(image_1)
# etc.
writer_semisuper.add_figure("testfig", fig, 0)
```

This shows exactly the same plot that you created, but with lower resolution. So if your plot works in jupyter or saved on disk it should also work in tensorboard.